# Automatically delete class instance when one of its attributes becomes dead

Tags: python

## Set Up

Say I have a `Snit`:

```
class Snit(): pass
```

And a `Snot`, which contains weak references to up to, say, four `Snit`s:

```
import weakref
class Snot():
    def __init__(self,s1=None,s2=None,s3=None,s4=None):
        self.s1 = weakref.ref(s1)
        self.s2 = weakref.ref(s2)
        self.s3 = weakref.ref(s3)
        self.s4 = weakref.ref(s4)
```

I also have a `Snot` factory:

```
def snot_factory(snits,w,x,y,z):
    return Snot(snits[w],snits[x],snits[y],snits[z])
```

And a `list` of `Snit`s (a `snit_list` as it were):

```
snit_list = []
for i in range(12):
    snit_list.append(Snit())
```

Now I make a list of `Snot`s using the `Snit`s in my `snit_list`:

```
snot_list = []
for i in range(3):
    snot_list.append(snot_factory(snit_list[4*i],snit_list[4*i+1],snit_list[4*i+2],snit_list[4*i+3]))
```

## The Problem

Whoops! I don't need `snit_list[3]` anymore, so I'll go ahead and remove it:

```
snit_list.pop(3)
```

But now I have a `Snot` hanging out there with a dead `Snit`:

```
snot_list[0].s4 # <weakref at 0x00BlahBlah; dead>
```

This cannot stand! A `Snot` with a dead `Snit` is - obviously - total nonsense.

So I would really like for any references to the `Snot` to at least return as `None` after one or more of its `Snit`s has been destroyed. But ideally, it would be even better for the `Snot` to be automatically removed from the `snot_list` list as well (`len(snot_list)` shrinks by the number of removed `Snot`s).

What's a good way of going about this?

## Clarification:

A `Snot` is an object that should only exist when there is a valid set of `Snit`s ("valid" means it has the same number of defined `Snit`s it was initialized with), with the following behavior:

1. If any one `Snit` in a `Snot` goes away (when no strong references remain), the `Snot` should also go away  (this is why I have set the `s1`, `s2`, etc to be weak references). Note that a `Snot` *could* have been initialized with 4, 3, 2, or 1 `Snit`. The number of `Snit`s doesn't matter, the *death* of the `Snit` is what matters.
2. If any one `Snot` that contains a reference to a `Snit` goes away, the `Snit` remains.
3. OPTIONAL: When a `Snot` is deleted, the data structure containing the reference to the `Snot` object is updated as well (the `Snot` gets `pop`ped)
4. OPTIONAL: When *ALL* the `Snots` that reference a certain `Snit` are gone, the `Snit` goes away too, and any data structures containing the `Snit` are updated as in #3 (the `Snit` gets `pop`ped).

So the ideal solution will allow me to set things up such that I can write code like this:

```
snits = get_snits_list(some_input_with_10000_snits)
snots = get_snots_list(some_cross_referenced_input_with_8000_snots)
#e.g.: the input file will say:
#snot number 12 is made of snits 1, 4, 7
#snot number 45 is made of snits 8, 7, 0, 14
do_stuff_with_snits()
snits.pop(7) #snit 7 is common to snot 12 and 45
assert len(snots) == 7998 #snots 12 and 45 have been removed
```

However, if this is too hard, I'd be fine with:

```
assert snots[12] == None
assert snots[45] == None
```

I am open to changing things around somewhat. For example, if it makes the design easier, I think it would be fine to remove the weak references to the `Snit`s, or to maybe move them instead to the list of `Snit`s instead of having the `Snot` members be weak refs (though I don't see how either of these changes would improve things).

I have also considered creating `Snot` subclasses - `ClearSnot` with 1 `Snit`, `YellowSnot` with 2 `Snit`s, `GreenSnot` with 3 `Snit`s, etc. I'm uncertain if this would make things easier to maintain, or more difficult.

Comment: in case anyone is wondering whether or not this question was simply a ploy to use snot_factory, the answer may be yes.

Comment: In a nutshell, snit no. ;-)

Comment: Could you clarify whether you want the access to the deleted attribute Snit `snots[0].s4` to return None, the Snot itself to return None when members are missing, or something else?

Comment: Your clarification is confusing.  ;)  According to your example, snot 12 has three snits in it, yet when you delete one of those snits, the entire snot becomes invalid?

Comment: Sorry, yes. I'll clarify better and del this comment, but yes, a `Snot` should no longer exist once any one of the `Snit`s it was created with is deleted (though it could be changed to another `Snit` in the list).

Comment: Or maybe it's a troll to get me to say this post is full of `Snit`? Or maybe that's *snot* what you're trying to do at all.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is truly automatic.  You'll need to either have a function that you run manually to check for dead `Snit`s, or have a function that is part of `Snot` that is called whenever anything interesting happens to a `Snot` to check for, and remove, dead `Snit`s.

For example:

```
class Snot:
    ...
    def __repr__(self):
        # check for and remove any dead Snits
        self._remove_dead_snits()
        return ...
    def _remove_dead_snits(self):
        if self.s1() is None:
             self.s1 = None
        ... # and so on and so forth
```

The fun part is adding that call to `_remove_dead_snits` for every interesting interaction with a `Snot` -- such as `__getitem__`, `__iter__`, and whatever else you may do with it.

---

Actually, thinking a bit more about this, if you only have the four possible `Snit`s per each `Snot` you could use a `SnitRef` descriptor -- here's the code, with some changes to your original:

```
import weakref

class Snit(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value  # just for testing
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Snit(%r)' % self.value

class SnitRef(object):   # 'object' not needed in Python 3
    def __get__(self, inst, cls=None):
        if inst is None:
            return self
        return self.ref()  # either None or the obj
    def __set__(self, inst, obj):
        self.ref = weakref.ref(obj)


class Snot(object):
    s0 = SnitRef()
    s1 = SnitRef()
    s2 = SnitRef()
    s3 = SnitRef()
    def __init__(self,s0=None,s1=None,s2=None,s3=None):
        self.s0 = s0
        self.s1 = s1
        self.s2 = s2
        self.s3 = s3

snits = [Snit(0), Snit(1), Snit(2), Snit(3)]
print snits
snot = Snot(*snits)
print(snot.s2)
snits.pop(2)
print snits
print(snot.s2)
```

and when run:

```
[Snit(0), Snit(1), Snit(2), Snit(3)]
Snit(2)
[Snit(0), Snit(1), Snit(3)]
None
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so you have a `Snot` with a variable amount of `Snit`s.

```
class Snot(object):

    def __init__(self, *snits):
        self.snits = [weakref.ref(s) for s in snits]

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, self.__class__) and other is not None:
            return NotImplemented
        # are all my snits still valid
        valid = all(s() for s in self.snits)
        if other is None:
            return not valid  # if valid is True, we are not equal to None
        else:
            # whatever it takes to see if this snot is the same as the other snot
```

Actually having the class instance disappear is going to take more work (such as having `dict` on the class to track them all, and then other data structures would just use weak-references -- but that could get ugly quick), so the next best thing will be having it become equal to `None` when any of its `Snit`s goes away.

---

I see that `snits` and `snots` are both `list`s -- is order important?  If order is not important you could use `set`s instead, and then it would be possible to have a performant solution where the the dead `snot` is actually removed from the data structure -- but it would add complexity: each `Snot` would have to keep track of which data struture it was in, and each `Snit` would have to keep a list of which `Snot`s it was in, and the magic would have to live in `__del__` which can lead to other problems...

Comment: I thought of doing something like your last paragraph describes but hadn't considered using a set. Order isn't necessarily important, though without some sort of order I don't know how I would refer to each specific `Snit` when a `Snot` constructed (instead of just referring to its index in the `snit_list`). I'll have to think about this some more.

Comment: @RickTeachey: Good point -- the `snits` would have to remain a `list`, but if the `snots` could become a `set`...

Comment: I suppose I could live with a `set` of `Snot`s.

Comment: Alright. So now to figure out how to track `Snot` references within the object instances. Here's the only idea I have come up with: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27063417/2437514

Comment: Referencing the other question here: you know, a `Snot` is really little more than a specialized `Snit` container. Maybe I should write a generalized container (as the performant solution you described) and subclass it as a `Snot`, a `SnitList`, and a `SnotList`. The `Snot` holds `Snit`s, the `SnitList` also holds `Snit`s, and the `SnotList` (or `set`, whatever) holds `Snot`s.