# Using the observer pattern to delete an Observer when a Subject has been "deleted" in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am attempting to implement a very simple [observer pattern](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Observer.html) in python.

Here is my `Observer` class (it's really just an interface and I guess I don't actually need it):

```
class Observer():
    def update(self,subject,message): pass
```

And my `Subject` class (aka `Observable`, but I prefer `Subject`):

```
class Subject():
    def __init__(self):
        self.observers = []
    def registerObserver(self, observer):
        if observer not in self.observers:
            self.observers.append(observer)
    def removeObserver(self, observer):
        self.observers.remove(observer)
    def notifyObservers(self, message = None):
        for observer in self.observers:
            observer.update(self,message)
```

Class `A` contains a nested `DelNotifier` class, which is a subclass of `Subject`. The idea that when a class `A` object is deleted (actually garbage collected, since it is in the `__del__` method), `A.DelNotifier` will notify all of its observers of the deletion.

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.delNotifier = A.DelNotifier(self)
    class DelNotifier(Subject):
        def __init__(self, outer):
            super(A.DelNotifier,self).__init__()
            self.outer = outer
        def notifyObservers(self):
            Subject.notifyObservers(self,"This is Class A object " + self.outer.name + ": I'm dying!")
    def registerB(self,observer):
        if not isinstance(observer,B): raise ValueError("Can only register Class B objects with Class A.")
        self.delNotifier.registerObserver(observer.Aobserver)
    def deleteme(self):
        print("Must notify observers of my impending doom first...")
        self.delNotifier.notifyObservers()
    def __str__(self):
        return "Class A object " + self.name
    def __del__(self):
        self.deleteme()
        print("Done notifying everyone, time to go gentle into that good night.")
```

Class `B` contains a nested `AObserver` class, which is a subclass of `Observer` and will receive the message from the class `A.DelNotifier` subject when an `A` has been deleted (again, in actuality this happens when the `A` object has been garbage collected):

```
class B():
    def __init__(self, name, a):
        self.name = name
        self.Aobserver = B.AObserver(self)
        a.registerB(self)
    class AObserver(Observer):
        def __init__(self,outer):
            super(B.AObserver,self).__init__()
            self.outer = outer
        def update(self,subject,message):
            print(str(self.outer) + " received message: '" + str(message) + "'")
            print("Time for", self.outer, "to die, too.")
            self.outer.__del__()
    def __str__(self):
        return "Class B object " + self.name
    def __del__(self):
        print("This is " + str(self) + ": now I'm dying, too!")
```

This design works when I call `__del__()` directly, however, some of the objects seem to be gc'd a second time when the session exits:

```
>>> a = A('a')
>>> b1 = B('b1', a)
>>> b2 = B('b2', a)
>>> a.__del__()
Must notify observers of my impending doom first...
Class B object b1 received message: 'This is Class A object a: I'm dying!'
Time for Class B object b1 to die, too.
This is Class B object b1: now I'm dying, too!
Class B object b2 received message: 'This is Class A object a: I'm dying!'
Time for Class B object b2 to die, too.
This is Class B object b2: now I'm dying, too!
Done notifying everyone, time to go gentle into that good night.
>>> exit()
Must notify observers of my impending doom first...
Class B object b1 received message: 'This is Class A object a: I'm dying!'
Time for Class B object b1 to die, too.
This is Class B object b1: now I'm dying, too!
Class B object b2 received message: 'This is Class A object a: I'm dying!'
Time for Class B object b2 to die, too.
This is Class B object b2: now I'm dying, too!
Done notifying everyone, time to go gentle into that good night.
This is Class B object b1: now I'm dying, too!
This is Class B object b2: now I'm dying, too!
```

Another problem, and I think this is more important, is that when I `del` a class `A` item from a list, the item is not immediately garbage collected and I cannot be sure that any registered `B` items have been deleted:

```
>>> b1 = B('b1',a[0])
>>> b2 = B('b2',a[0])
>>> del a[0]
## Note that items are not deleted until session exits
>>> exit()
Must notify observers of my impending doom first...
Class B object b1 received message: 'This is Class A object a: I'm dying!'
Time for Class B object b1 to die, too.
This is Class B object b1: now I'm dying, too!
Class B object b2 received message: 'This is Class A object a: I'm dying!'
Time for Class B object b2 to die, too.
This is Class B object b2: now I'm dying, too!
Done notifying everyone, time to go gentle into that good night.
##Note that the class B objects get gc'd a second time....???
This is Class B object b1: now I'm dying, too!
This is Class B object b2: now I'm dying, too!
```

In addition to these problems, I am aware of the many many problems inherent in relying on the `__del__` method to do anything other than cleaning up an object after it has been gc'd, and that it should probably be avoided for the purposes I am trying to employ. But I don't know of another way.

What would be a better way to do this? I have thought about trying to use a context manager (`with`) to delete things after I'm done using them, but I have no experience doing that. If that would be a good option, how would I go about doing that? What would it look like?

## EDIT: Clarification of desired behavior

I'll attempt to clear up some of the (understandable) confusion.

I've simplified the code quite a bit above, but `B` is an object that depends on an object `A`. If a `B`'s `A` goes away, that `B` should go away. I'll have some container (using a `list` here) of As and of Bs:

```
As = [A('a'+str(i)) for i in range(10)]
Bs = [B('b'+str(i),As[i]) for i in range(10)] #Bs made of As
del As[0] #whoops, don't need As[0] anymore
assert Bs[0] is None #ERROR!
#or using pop:
As.pop(0)
assert Bs[0] is None #ERROR!
```

Also [see my previous question from the other day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27051119/automatically-delete-class-instance-when-one-of-its-attributes-becomes-dead/27053247) which helped lead me to this whole idea of using the observer pattern in the first place.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why don't you simply rely on the GC? Seems a bit odd to work against it, since GC is hardcore in Python.

Comment: I'll have a list of As and a list of Bs. I want to know that if I do, for example, 'if Bs[0]:', I'll get a False if the corresponding A object or objects has been removed from As.

Comment: That's too much code for my exhausted brain to grasp ATM, but I do have a weak amount of partially relevant information you might try. There's a [dispose pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in `C#` that basically keeps a flag saying whether the object was deleted or not. Set a flag when you call `__del__`, like `self.__deleted = True`, and then check it before you do anything. `def __del__(self): if not self.__del: YOUR STUFF HERE / self.__del = True`, or something like that. It may just mask an architectural problem, though. But it might help.

Comment: It's a good suggestion. I think it would require a custom container to make it all work though.

Comment: What's wrong with using a normal weakref?

Comment: I've tried a weakref in various permutations but I haven't been able to get the behavior I want. I'll put up some more sample usage of the way I want things to behave.

Comment: A few points. 1) GC [may never happen](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1481508/1174169) and `del` only decrements the reference count (things I just discovered). In fact, when I call `del a` in your first case, I get no output at all. 2) I had to add `object` to the base class `Subject` and `Observer` to get this code to compile in `2.7.6`. 3) I do not see the repeated notification that you mentioned. When I type `exit()` after calling `a.__del()__` explicitly, it just exits with no output. 4) deleting an item from a list `del a_list[0]` only *removes the item from the list*.

Comment: To clarify, in case `3` above, I *do* see the output when I call `a.__del()__` explicitly, but no repeated output on `exit()`.

Comment: Code is Python 3 (tags edited). I was just thinking the repeated output might be because I'm holding strong references to `B` objects in the `a.observers` list, so I guess it makes sense that their `__del__` may be called multiple times. Not sure why you're not seeing it. They should probably be weak references. I am aware that del only removes from the list - I'll be adding more code to clarify desired behavior.

Comment: So from what I can figure so far, `a=A('a')` creates 2 references to `a`. One is the variable `a`, and the other is the `outer` member of the `DelNotifier` you've created. This appears to be why I can't get `del a` to call the `__del__` method. It's never fully dereferenced. I can call `del a.delNotifer` and then `del a` and both `__del__` methods get called, but of course I get an Exception in the second case because of my first deletion. So... I'm guessing at this point I should attempt my own rewrite :D

Comment: Tried to clarify things in my question. Would not be opposed to a rewrite!

Comment: If you're depending on `__del__` to be called via `del X`, then all references must be removed to the item before the delete will be called. Since you're creating an array, there will *always* be references in this array until you remove them. Maybe you don't want to rely on `del` and could instead just explicitly do whatever you want to do. But in any case, nothing will set the reference to `None` automatically in the array unless you explicitly code it to do so!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a significant amount of code difference to account for your requirement of automatically maintaining a list of references, and cleaning up when the references are deleted. I've added a `Manager` class to accomplish this, and a second pass `deleted()` event that is a hook for the Manager to clean up the lists it is maintaining. I'm re-posting the full, modified code here as it wasn't trivial to update my previous answer.

I believe this fully satisfies the question you've asked. Perhaps not the reason *why* you need this in the first place, but I think you asked that in the other question.

We need weak references to make this work:

```
import weakref
```

The `Observer` interface gets a new method to be called *after* `deleted()`

```
class Observer(object):
    def update(self,subject,message): pass

    def deleting(self,subject):
        ''' the subject is being deleted '''
        pass

    def deleted(self,subject):
        pass
```

A manager class maintains the lists of subjects and observers

```
class Manager(Observer):

    def __init__(self, ):
        self._subjects = []
        self._observers = []

    def monitorSubject(self, subject):
        self._subjects.append( weakref.ref(subject) )

        # observe the subject for deletion to
        # trigger list maintenance on "deleted"
        subject.registerObserver(self)

    def monitorObserver(self, observer):
        self._observers.append( weakref.ref(observer) )

    def deleted(self, subject):
        ''' a subject was deleted, remove it from the list.
        deleting() is called first, and the observers delete themselves.
        deleted() is called next, and is a hook for the manager to
        cleanup any dead subjects and observers '''

        # calling a weakref returns the original object, and `None` when the
        # reference is dead
        def isNotDead(r):
            return not r()==None

        # remove any dead subjects
        print 'Removing dead subjects...'
        self._subjects = filter(isNotDead, self._subjects)

        # remove any dead observers            
        print 'Removing dead observers...'
        self._observers = filter(isNotDead, self._observers, )

    def __str__(self,):
        return "[Manager] Subjects:{0}, Observers:{1}".format(
            ','.join([str(r()) for r in self._subjects]),
            ','.join([str(r()) for r in self._observers])
        )
```

The differences in the subject are noted in the comments, but primarily there is a second pass to call `deleted`. The first pass of `deleting` notifies the observers, while the second pass of `deleted` notifies the manager. Also, the `__del__` routine uses weak refs to iterate over, as some of them get deleted along the way.

```
class Subject(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.observers = []

    def __del__(self, ):
        ''' on deletion, notify the observers '''
        print "{0}.__del__".format(self)

        # copy the observer list, then remove all references to the observers
        # NEW - use weakrefs here, or they will not be properly deleted later
        obs = [weakref.ref(o) for o in self.observers]

        # clear all strong references to the observers
        self.observers = []

        # notify all observers that we were deleted
        # ** only if they are not already deleted **
        for o in obs:
            if not o() == None:
                o().deleting(self)

        # NEW - second pass to allow the Manager to cleanup
        # ** only if they are not already deleted **
        for o in obs:
            if not o() == None:
                o().deleted(self)

    def registerObserver(self, observer):
        if observer not in self.observers:
            self.observers.append(observer)

    def removeObserver(self, observer):
        self.observers.remove(observer)

    def notifyObservers(self, message = None):
        for observer in self.observers:
            observer.update(self,message)
```

Same as before, with simplified string formatting

```
class A(Subject):
    ''' A is just a subject '''
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(A,self).__init__()
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return "A[ {0} ]".format(self.name)
```

B is the same as before

```
class B(Observer):
    ''' class B is an observer of A '''

    def __init__(self, name, a):
        self.name = name

        # don't keep a reference to 'a', or 'a' will not be deleted!
        a.registerObserver(self)

    def __str__(self):
        return "B[ {0} ]".format(self.name)

    def __del__(self):
        print("{0}.__del__".format(self))

    def deleting(self, subject):
        ''' notification from the subject (A) that it is being deleted. I'm
        assuming here that the subject is actually the one we registered in
        __init__, since I couldn't store a reference or else __del__ would
        not have been called! '''
        print "B[{0}].deleting, subject={1}".format(self.name, subject)

        del self
```

Some code to execute the file:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    mgr = Manager()

    # keep strong references to the subjects, because
    # we will delete them explicitly
    a1 = A('a1')
    a2 = A('a2')
    mgr.monitorSubject(a1)
    mgr.monitorSubject(a2)

    # monitor observers directly, and do NOT keep
    # strong references or they will not be deleted
    mgr.monitorObserver( B('b1', a1) )
    mgr.monitorObserver( B('b2', a1) )
    mgr.monitorObserver( B('b3', a2) )
    mgr.monitorObserver( B('b4', a2) )

    # show the starting state
    print mgr

    print "Deleting a1..."
    del a1
    print mgr

    print "Deleting a2..."
    del a2
    print mgr
```

And the output:

```
    #  OUTPUT (some newlines added)
    #
    #  [Manager] Subjects:A[ a1 ],A[ a2 ], Observers:B[ b1 ],B[ b2 ],B[ b3 ],B[ b4 ]
    #
    #  Deleting a1...
    #  A[ a1 ].__del__
    #  B[ b1 ].__del__
    #  B[ b2 ].__del__
    #  Removing dead subjects...
    #  Removing dead observers...
    #  [Manager] Subjects:A[ a2 ], Observers:B[ b3 ],B[ b4 ]
    #
    #  Deleting a2...
    #  A[ a2 ].__del__
    #  B[ b3 ].__del__
    #  B[ b4 ].__del__
    #  Removing dead subjects...
    #  Removing dead observers...
    #
    #  [Manager] Subjects:, Observers:
```

Comment: So, in any event, you see this is non-trivial to implement (maybe you knew that already). **And** it is fragile: if you have *any* references to *any* of the subjects or observers elsewhere, the automatic calling of `__del__` will not happen. Can you really ensure in your application that nobody will ever keep a reference to a `B` or an `A` (a `Snit` or a `Snot`)?

Comment: Wow this is a lot to take in! Thanks for all the effort you obviously put in.

Answer (score 1):

Caveat: I'm working in `2.7.3`, so some of this may be a little different.

I've got some code that seems to work a bit better than what you have. Hopefully it'll raise some relevant points.

First, the observer interface shows a `deleting` event that will be called when a subject is going away. As you've noted, this isn't really necessary but I like to declare my interfaces explicitly.

```
class Observer(object):
    def update(self,subject,message): pass

    def deleting(self,subject):
        ''' the subject is being deleted '''
        pass
```

Next, the Subject class will be responsible for handling the `__del__`, and notifying all observers. This is a bit simplified, and takes the code away from `A`, and gets rid of all internal classes from your initial example. In the `Subject`'s `__del__` method, I copy the observers, clear them out (to remove all references), then call the `deleting` method to allow the observers to delete themselves.

```
class Subject(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.observers = []

    def __del__(self, ):
        ''' on deletion, notify the observers '''
        print "Subject.__del__".format(self)

        # copy the observer list, then remove all references to the observers
        obs = self.observers[:]
        self.observers = []

        # notify all observers that we were deleted
        for o in obs:
            o.deleting(self)

    def registerObserver(self, observer):
        if observer not in self.observers:
            self.observers.append(observer)
```

I've left out the `removeObserver` and `notifyObservers` because I'm not using them in this solution (clearly they are useful otherwise).

The class `A` is then just a simple `Subject` and doesn't provide anything but a naming functionality here. I've removed the restriction that only `B`s can register to `A`s for simplicity, and I don't think it's necessary to solve the problem.

```
class A(Subject):
    ''' A is just a subject '''
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(A,self).__init__()
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return "A[name={0}]".format(self.name)
```

Then `B`, as an observer automatically adds itself as an observer of A, on creation. And when the observed subject is deleted, notification is received through the `deleting` method. Since there is only one observed subject, I assume it is the `A` passed into `__init__` and delete `self`. It's important (at least in 2.7) to not store references to `a` within `B`, or it appears that `__del__` may never get called by the gc (this could be my misunderstanding of the `gc`).

```
class B(Observer):
    ''' class B is an observer of A '''

    def __init__(self, name, a):
        self.name = name

        # don't keep a reference to 'a', or 'a' will not be deleted!
        a.registerObserver(self)

    def __str__(self):
        return "B[name={0}]".format(self.name)

    def __del__(self):
        print("{0}.__del__".format(self))

    def deleting(self, subject):
        ''' notification from the subject (A) that it is being deleted. I'm
        assuming here that the subject is actually the one we registered in
        __init__, since I couldn't store a reference or else __del__ would
        not have been called! '''
        print "B.deleting, subject={0}".format(subject)

        del self
```

With this code, I get the output:

```
>>> from main import A, B
>>> a = A('a')
>>> B('b1', a)
<main.B object at 0x00000000022938D0>
>>> B('b2', a)
<main.B object at 0x0000000002293B70>

>>> del a
Subject.__del__
B.deleting, subject=A[name=a]
B.deleting, subject=A[name=a]
B[name=b1].__del__

>>> import gc
>>> gc.collect()
B[name=b2].__del__
0
```

which seems more like what you want, except that `b2` isn't immediately garbage collected.

**EDIT: Added example based on further clarification of behavior**

```
>>> from main import A, B
>>>
>>> As = [A('a'+str(i)) for i in range(10)]
>>> Bs = [B('b'+str(i),As[i]) for i in range(10)]
```

Deleting an item from the `As` array removes the item from the list, and thus decrements the refcount, and the subject `a1` is deleted, which notifies `b1` that the subject is deleted. `b1` then calls `del` on itself, but is not deleted because of the reference in the `Bs` array.

```
>>> del As[1]
Subject.__del__
B.deleting, subject=A[name=a1]
```

Setting the reference in the `Bs` array to `None` will reduce refcount to 0, and thus call `__del__`

```
>>> Bs[1] = None
B[name=b1].__del__
```

Showing that the `Bs` array needs some cleanup, manually

```
>>> len(As)
9
>>> len(Bs)
10

>>> del Bs[1]
>>> len(Bs)
9
```

And that the `gc` doesn't have any work to do:

```
>>> import gc
>>> gc.collect()
0
```

The rest get cleaned up on `exit()`

Comment: Wife on the box right now so can't try it: I wonder, what if I use weakrefs in the Bs list...

Comment: Adding `weakref(B(...))` does, in my limited testing, cause `B.__del__` to be called immediately after doing `del As[x]`. But then the lengths of the As and Bs are out of sync. The items in `Bs` are then marked as dead weakrefs: `del As[1], print Bs[1]` gives `<weakref at 00000000022BD408; dead>`. Which I suppose you could remove all deleted refs with a `filter`.

Comment: Getting closer. It really needs to be `None` instead of a dead weakref, or go away completely (even better). I think, based on your very helpful answer and thinking about it more, there is nothing for it but to make a custom container class if I really want to get the behavior I have in mind.

Comment: Nothing will automatically delete items from a list, set, dictionary, etc. for you. You have to explicitly delete the items yourself. So, maybe this *is* an architectural issue. Is the purpose of your solution fully described in your other linked question (which is still unanswered (?)). If so, maybe there's a better solution to what you're doing than trying to magically delete items from a list (plus, the notes I linked about the `gc` not being required to run may even make this solution completely implausible)

Comment: Right, I understand about how depending on the gc to get things done is problematic. It very well may be an architectural issue that can be solved in a better way, I don't know. The linked question pretty fully describes the problem. I thought this (observer pattern) was going to be the solution! Grrr.